# hyundai accent 2005 engin sound wired only when AC is on

Tags: ac, hyundai, accent

I just change my oil, filter, and changed air intake system with one of K&N air filter. After all of that, my car starts making weird noises ONLY when AC is turned on. I mean, when AC is on, I have rough start up to second gear. Motor makes some weird noise. It's like something bashing into car. Nobody in my area seems to be able to find the issue, so I came here to find the solution.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

there is a pretty strong drain on the engine when the AC is on and working properly.  About 5 hp .   If your system has a clog or something, it could be using more than that.  Additionally if your car needs a tune up, it is going to respond worse.  Your car SHOULD idle faster when the AC is on.  If that's not working properly, you may need the idle control soleniod replaced.